# EventWaitHandle - multiple threads = inconsistent behaviour

Tags: .net, multithreading, event-wait-handle

I am trying to setup some comms with a device where you can send a command and receive a response.  I do however want to ensure that I control a timeout flag to prevent indefinite wait times.

I did something like this:

```
private volatile EventWaitHandle _signal;

public void Send()
{
    // Do something

    _signal.WaitOne(30000);

    // Continue with something else

    _signal.Reset();
}

public void Receive() 
{
    _signal.Set();
}
```

My question is, if I have multiple threads (let's say 2 for this example) that can access the Send method and the following scenario:

Thread A:

```
// Sends a "listen" command, but no response is received 
Send();
```

Thread B:

```
// Sends a "cancel" command and response (success) is received
Send();
```

I get inconsistent results, i.e. sometimes both threads continue when I get a response for the second command (cancel) which I can understand, but sometimes the first thread will hit the 30000ms timeout - which I cannot explain.

Any advice as to what I am missing and/or doing wrong?

Comment: Aren't you using `AutoResetEvent`? You need to use `ManualResetEvent`, otherwise it will reset automatically when the waiting thread is signaled. In fact, you probably don't really want to use wait handles at all. There's most likely a better solution to what you're trying to do, especially if you can afford to use .NET 4.5.1. Why is this multi-threaded in the first place?

Comment: Using ManualResetEvent and multi-threaded in order to cancel a pending response, i.e. command sent, but I need to be able to cancel it before I receive a response.
(Limited to .Net 4.0 unfortunately)

Comment: .NET 4.0 should still be enough to enable you to use asynchronous I/O for the purpose, although 4.5 makes this much much easier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An EventWaitHandle is not the appropriate synchronization object here.  You require [*mutual exclusion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) so that only *one* thread can be in a state where it sent a command and is waiting for the response.  In other words, threads must strictly take their turn to talk to the device.

A ManualResetEvent doesn't give you that guarantee, as soon as you call Set() then **all** the threads that are blocking on the WaitOne() call will be unblocked.  If that's more than one then your program will malfunction when two or more threads try to send a command at the same time.

A Mutex provides MUTual EXclusion.  That's how it got its name.

Comment: This makes sense, but if I exclude any other threads how would I cancel the current request (on the thread that is blocking)?

Comment: You gave no hint whatsoever in your question what it might be blocking on.  It is waiting for some kind of I/O request to complete, perhaps.  Make it wait on a cancel request as well with, say, WaitAny().  That's a guess.  You then release the Mutex as well of course.